# How to know if the cursor / selection is on an empty line?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm currently struggling with a very simple issue. 
For a macro, I'd like to know if my cursor is on an empty line or not. I thought to use `Len()` or `Count` but they always return `1` (even if there are more character on the current line).

I assume that using a `Range` rather than `Selection`could help but I have no idea how to do it (I'm not very skilled with vba-word).
I guess I could select the whole line (how?) and then `if Selection.Characters.Count > 1 Then [...]` but it seems ugly and unefficient.

Thanks in advance for any help or piece of advice,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ...

```
If Asc(ThisDocument.Characters(Selection.Start)) = 13 And Asc(ThisDocument.Characters(Selection.Start + 1)) = 13 Then
    MsgBox "y"
End If
```

`ThisDocument.Characters` contains all the text in the document, split into individual characters (eg letters/digits/spaces/etc)

`Asc(...)` gets the character code for a particular character

`13` is the code for a carriage return (new line)

`Selection.Start` refers to the character before the caret/cursor

`Selection.Start + 1` refers to the character after the caret

---

As advised by @Ezor, this may not work on all versions of Word VBA, so an alternative would be to use `ActiveDocument` rather than `ThisDocument`, eg

```
If Asc(ActiveDocument.Characters(Selection.Start)) = 13 And Asc(ActiveDocument.Characters(Selection.Start + 1)) = 13 Then
    MsgBox "y"
End If
```

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for this answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't work since I've got the following error 

_The requested member of the collection does not exist _ --> error 5941. 

However, looking for carriage return is probably better than counting the number of character. I'll dig into this.

Comment: I tested it on my machine and it works ;0) Have you tried placing those three lines of code into a separate `Sub` and then running just that `Sub`, when you have selected a blank line? Also, what version of Word are you using, and what text did you test it on?

Comment: Yes, I tried that into a separate `Sub`. I solved the  error by using `ActiveDocument` instead of `ThisDocument`
However, it seems to aim a charactere at random in the line, and not the first one before/after the cursor.

I'm using Word 2010, for a regular document written by colleagues and I

EDIT : Actualy, each time I launch this `Sub`, the index `Selection.Start` jumps by 24...

Comment: So it seems to be ok if I do this
`Asc(ActiveDocument.Characters(Selection.Start - 24))` which is weird

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer to include your findings. It's difficult to asses your problem without having access to the actual document! Sorry :0(

Comment: That is weird! Does it work on every blank line in the document with that new code?

Comment: yes it does (or at least on the ones I tested). I even works for non-empty line. 
My document is very simple. i can't show it here but I assume this piece of code should work everwhere. I don't understand why this 24 appears !

Comment: It could be all sorts of things! Special/unprinted characters at the start of the document would be a prime candidate, but as I say, without the document it's impossible to say. Glad you got it sorted! ;0)

Comment: Don't use `ThisDocument` because `ThisDocument` refers specifically to the document in which the macro is saved. Always use `ActiveDocument` unless you know WHY you're using `ThisDocument` (for a specific reason).

Answer (score 5):

You ask about empty lines... There's an important difference in Word between "empty paragraph" and "empty line". Most people mean paragraph when they use the term "line", but a paragraph ends in ANSI 13, while a line ends in ANSI 11 (Shift+Enter). Assuming you mean paragraph...

There are any number of ways to go about it, but a simple one to test how many characters are in the paragraph. An empty paragraph has only 1 character, ANSI 13:

```
If Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Characters.Count = 1 Then
  'Only a paragraph mark - the paragraph (line) is empty
End If
```

If you really mean "line" it's a bit more complicated. A line may be empty, while the paragraph could contain additional content on other lines. Here's an example

[image]

In addition, a Selection might not be a single point, which is important to have when asking whether the Selection is in an empty line / paragraph.

The following procedure first checks the `Selection.Type` and if it's not an IP, nothing happens. It then checks whether the selection is in an empty paragraph (as above). If the paragraph contains more than one, it's necessary to determine what is immediately before and immediately after the Selection. Either ANSI 13 or ANSI 11 may be in these positions, nothing else.

The Selection is extended to search ANSI 11 and ANSI 13, but the search is limited to one character. If the search is successful, 1 and -1 will be returned, otherwise 0. If 1 and -1 one then the selection is in an empty line, even if the paragraph contains multiple lines, as in the image.

In the image, the first "line" is an empty paragraph; the second is not empty; the third is an empty line; the fourth is not empty; the fifth is an empty line.

```
Sub EmptyLineOrPara()
    Dim nrChars As Long
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Dim nrCharsMovedForward As Long
    Dim nrCharsMovedBackward As Long

    If Selection.Type = wdSelectionIP Then
        Set rng = Selection.paragraphs(1).Range
        nrChars = rng.Characters.Count
        If nrChars = 1 Then
            Debug.Print "Empty paragraph"
        ElseIf nrChars > 1 Then
            nrCharsMovedForward = Selection.MoveEndUntil(Chr(11) & Chr(13), 1)
            nrCharsMovedBackward = Selection.MoveStartUntil(CSet:=Chr(11) & Chr(13), Count:=-2)
            If nrCharsMovedForward = 1 And nrCharsMovedBackward = -1 Then
                Debug.Print "Empty line"
            ElseIf Selection.Fields.Count > 0 Then
                Debug.Print "Selection contains fields!"
            Else
                Debug.Print "Not empty"
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That is awesome ! Thanks a lot for your post, that will help me (an probably many others) :)